# VBA code only works when I run it steps by steps(F8)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code when runs perfectly by hitting F8 (running steps by steps). However, it doesn't work when hitting F5(running it). I guess it's because my code is kind of in loop but I couldn't figure out what's wrong.

```
Sub BLKReport()

Dim IRow As Long
Dim lcntr As Long

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim b As Long
Dim r As String
Dim i As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CSV File")
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Destination")

lrow = Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
For lcntr = lrow To 1 Step -1
        
        If ws.Cells(lcntr, 9).Value = "25" Then
           r = ws.Cells(lcntr, 2).Value
           For i = lcntr To 1 Step -1
            If ws.Cells(i, 2).Value = r Then
                ws.Rows(i).Copy
                ws1.Activate
                b = i 
                ws1.Cells(b - 1, 1).Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste
                ws.Activate
            
            
            ElseIf ws.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value <> r Then
           
            End If
           Next i
             
        End If
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
        ws.Select

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You know that `lrow = Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row` is using the current sheet and not one of the workbooks you have in a variable.

Comment: You could improve the reliability of your code significantly by reducing your use of `.Activate` and `.Select`. Your code can be simplified into `ws.Rows(i).Copy Destination:=ws1.Cells(i - 1, 1).Row`. Which doesn't rely on `ActiveSheet` or `Select`

Comment: Is `lrow = ActiveSheet.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row` the intended behavior? I know `ActiveSheet` was omitted but VBA implies it.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I am pretty new to VBA and I am still learning. @Toddleson

Comment: Hi @JerryJeremiah, You perfectly solved my problem. Thanks